# Error When Applying 'GroupBy' LINQ Clause: "At least one object must implement IComparable."

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group a collection of custom entity object by username, then by position.  For a specific user, when I get to the second 'groupby', I always get the error:

"At least one object must implement IComparable."

The user in question has a username "#gill'n it".  When I execute the first "GroupBy" on that suername, it returns an anonymous type of Count=6, which is correct, but the number of elements in the type is 8 where the final two are null. I think those final two nulls are causing my problem, but I can't figure out where they're coming from.

```
     List<CheatSheet> allRelevantCheatSheets = CheatSheet.GetCheatSheets(Globals.FOOString)   // only grade football sheets
                                              .Where(x => x.Username != String.Empty)      // only grade user sheets
                                              .Where(x => x.SeasonCode == currrentFOOSeason)  // only grade sheet for the current season
                                              .Where(x => x.LastUpdated < kickoffDate)         // only grade sheets before the kickoff date
                                              .Where(x => x.Positions.Count == 1)    // only grade single-position sheets
                                              .Where(x => (bool)x.MappedProperties[CSProperty.PPRLeague.ToString()] == false) // only grade standard socring sheets
                                              .ToList();

  foreach (var userSheetGroup in allRelevantCheatSheets.GroupBy(x => x.Username).OrderBy(x => x.Key))
  {

    int newCheatSheetID = 0;
    groupCounter++;

    // then group userSheets by position
    foreach (var targetUserPositionalSheetGroup in userSheetGroup.GroupBy(x => x.Positions[0]).OrderBy(x => x.Key))
    {
      // finally limit the type of sheet returned to only 1 (the latest one ordered by date), must cast to list in order to avoid casting error, then take first item
      CheatSheet userTopPositionSheet = (CheatSheet)targetUserPositionalSheetGroup.OrderBy(x => x.CheatSheetID).OrderBy(x => x.Positions[0]).OrderByDescending(x => x.LastUpdated).Take(1).ToList()[0];
      newCheatSheetID = ArchiveCheatSheet(userTopPositionSheet);
      if (newCheatSheetID == 0)
      {
        errorCounter++;
      }
      else
      {
        sheetCounter++;

        ArchiveCheatSheetItems(userTopPositionSheet.CheatSheetID, newCheatSheetID);
      }
    }
  }
```

[image: GroupBy Error]

Comment: What is type of x.Positions[0]? Are you sure that all elements of userSheetGroup have at least one element in x.Positions?

Comment: -1 It is not clear what Linq provider you are using. It seems like LinqToObjects, but the distinction is important, as only L2O uses the equality operators in your code.

Comment: Yes all elements had at least one Position object, otherwise the first query would fail-> Where(x => x.Positions.Count == 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the `null` values are a red herring.  Internal implementations of collections in .NET often seem to have underlying element counts that are powers of two, likely to maintain [amortized time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis) in collection manipulation operations.  The count of 6 is correct.

Second, if the type of `x.Positions[0]` does not implement `IComparable`, and no default comparer can be found, you would get the specified exception due to `.OrderBy(x => x.Key)` because there is no definition of how to sort the elements.  If this is the case, use the two-argument extension method (three-argument if you count `this`) that allows you to specify the `IComparer` to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549422(v=vs.110).aspx.  Or, if you have ownership of the type of `x.Positions[0]`, modify it to implement `IComparable`.

Comment: The problem was indeed the non-implementation if IComparable, but it was the GroupBy clause which was causing the exception, not the OrderBy.  The correct solution was to group by a property of the Position class, ie "GroupBy(x => x.Positions[0].PositionCode)"

Comment: Without actually looking it up, I would have presumed that `GroupBy` would complain about lacking `IEquatable` rather than `IComparable`. Glad you got it working in any case.